# iPhone 5s fingerprint sensor with arduino or raspberry pi

Tags: iphone, arduino, raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I have got just the home-button from an iPhone 5s and I thought about that I could use the sensor with a Raspberry PI or Arduino to scan fingerprints & more.
Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

There is adafruit fingerprint sensor but going the salvage path would be hard because of the hole Apple incovience with the close source. Be sure not to use it for commercial use but if your just fooling around it should be fine.